# Корректно ли предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Думаю что все корректно, но все таки прошу подтвердить корректность следующего предложения:

> Насколько сильно она может быть загружена и при этом не соскользнуть?

В том смысле что:

> Насколько сильно она может быть загружена так чтобы при этом не соскользнуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба предложения некорретны, особенно первое - в нем инфинитив повисает в воздухе (не связывается с "может" или с чем-либо другим). Вторая часть могла бы сочетаться с *другим типом* вопроса:

> Может ли она быть сильно загружена и при этом не соскользнуть?

В вашем же исходном варианте для исправления достаточно заменить "и" на "чтобы" ("при этом" можно опустить):

> Насколько сильно она может быть загружена, *чтобы* не
> соскользнуть?

Во втором (пояснительном) варианте вопроса - стилистическая неточность: "так" больше свойственно утверждению, чем вопросу (Она должна быть загружена так, чтобы не соскользнуть), и это слово нужно опустить.

Comment: "Она может быть сильно загружена и при этом не соскользнуть." -- а это верно? вроде инфинитив связывается с "может", нет?

Comment: Это повествовательное предложение верно, но в вопросе - ошибка: "насколько сильно" - это корректный вопрос к _первой_ части высказывания (о _величине нагрузки_); когда две его части соединены союзом "**и**", приходится отнести тот же вопрос и ко второй части, но тогда читается странное "_насколько сильно_ может при этом _не соскользнуть_".

Comment: Ок. А как быть в таких предложениях: Либо Вася либо Маша остался сегодня дома. Хорошо англичанам, а в русском придется городить огороды :)